# Custom Search Element Control API between two dates

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I m using Google Custom Search Element API 2.0 for making a search.

Need to have results based on dates, 
between from dates and to date for the postings.

Is there a way to pass FROM and TO DATES to the API before making a call, so as to get the filtered results based on dates.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var cx = 'KEY';
        var gcse = document.createElement('script');
        gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
        gcse.async = true;
        gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
    })();
</script>
```

Code snapshot attached :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBafx.png)

Comment: please don't paste your code as screenshots. Bring it in the question and wrap it with code highlighter.

Comment: Hi @Manmohan_singh , I have updated the code too.